# setcookie does not work

Tags: php, setcookie

I have a simple file called index.php. I need to pass it a querystring that will be stored inside a never-expiring cookie. The file looks exactly like this :

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['referrer_id']))
{
    $querystringWithJunk = $_GET['referrer_id'];
    $querystringArray = explode('/', $querystringWithJunk);

    setcookie("referrer_id", $querystringArray[0], time() + 60*60*24*365*100);
}?>
```

However, no cookie is set. What is inside referrer_id is a simple integer (in the tests I made, it's 1). Function setCoookie return true and everything seems to works fine but no cookie is set. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Time is bigger than int, so I think result is negative, and then cookie is set into past, what means, it is deleted. Set time to 3 years instead of 100.